# In R programming, convert factor type to integer type of a column in matrix

Tags: regex, r, data-analysis

I have a column with the name donations
it has values like,

```
$50,000
$43
$456
```

etc..

I want to convert this to integer type so that I can take mean, sum etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$newcol <- as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", df$donations))
#  donations newcol
#1   $50,000  50000
#2       $43     43
#3      $456    456
```

You can use the pattern `"[$,]"` to eliminate the commas and dollar signs. The brackets represent character classes that we can define.